# Is it enough to change only the MAC address of a VM to enhance anonimity?

Tags: anonymity, mac-address

I'm learning a bit about Kali linux, and I heard that it is a good practice to change the MAC address of your Kali VM so that no particular action can be traced to you (at the link level).
However, as far as I understand, changing the MAC address of your VM simply hides the internal MAC, but to the router, the requests look like they come from the host of the VM, so it doesn't make sense not to change the MAC address of the host as well.

Therefore, my question is

> Does it make sense to only change the MAC address of the VM?

I'm a newbie with these things, so I apologize for the silly question.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the networking configuration; is the VM network NAT or bridged, and is the host's network adapter wired or wireless?

Comment: I didn't know much about VM networking. You're right, it all depends on whether or not it is NAT or bridge. Now, why does it matter if the host's adapter is wired or wireless?

Comment: see my answer for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard that it is a good practice to change the MAC address of
>   your Kali VM so that no particular action can be traced to you (at the
>   link level)

To rephrase, changing the MAC address *may* make it harder for the network administrator to identify who is behind any actions they are monitoring. It has no effect beyond the router/gateway, as you have noted.

The result and effectiveness of changing the VM's MAC address will vary widely depending on the configuration of the VM and host's networking. Some of the following may vary between hypervisor but should be true in general.

### NAT VM Adapter

If the VM is on a NAT'd network provided by the host machine, changing the VM's MAC address has no effect for your purposes, as the "real" network is already behind a router (your host), so the "real" network will only see the host's MAC address.

### Bridged VM Adapter

A bridged adapter places the VM directly on the same network as the host, often by using a custom driver that can inject packets onto the network and retrieve them as well. In this case, the VM will have its own MAC address that is independent of the host. In this case, changing your MAC address should have the desired effect.

One caveat is with regards to wireless networking. If the bridged adapter in use is a wireless adapter, the host will substitute the source MAC with its own (the MAC address is used in 802.11; the wireless access point would not recognize frames from the VM's MAC address as there is no such authenticated client). In this case, it would not help for what you want.

### USB Adapter

Finally, if you are using a USB network adapter that is passed through to the VM, wired or wireless, it is completely independent from the host and will work as expected for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, definitely much clearer now. Is it possible to get the same results from a bridged VM with a wired host, but with wireless?

Comment: @Daniel I don't think so, since the host is the one that sets up the wireless connection. The only workaround, as mentioned, would be to use a USB wireless adapter that is passed to the VM.